# Django: NameError 'Business' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Not sure what is causing this error. Please help

```
NameError at /dash/
name 'Business' is not defined

Exception Location: /home/src/common/models.py in ImageBank, line 38
```

Here's the model:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_type = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessType)
    business_service_type = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceType)
    establishment_type = models.ForeignKey(EstablishmentType)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(ImageBank)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    website = models.URLField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The View:

```
def dashview(request):
    coupon = Coupon.objects.filter()
    bdnspk = request.user.id
    user = request.user.username
    bdns = Business.objects.values('name').get(id=bdnspk)
    context = {
        'coupon':coupon,
        'bdns':bdns,
        'user':user


    }
    return render_to_response(
        'dash/dash.html',
        {},
        context,
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

EDIT: my models is located in /home/src/common/models.py but my django app is in /home/proj/site/ How do I import that?

ImageBank model:

```
class ImageBank(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/bank")

    def url(self):
        return self.image.url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at your error: `Exception Location: /home/src/common/models.py in ImageBank, line 38` the problem exists in the ImageBank class, which you also seem to be using a ForeignKey reference to in the logo field.

I'm assuming that what the issue is is that you are referencing Business before it is defined as something like a ForeignKey reference inside a field in ImageBank. If this is the case, is ImageBank defined before the Business model inside your models.py? Because doing so will throw this error. The proper way of doing circular ForeignKey references would be to enforce a single ForeignKey with a unique constraint.

Django has this concept built in as a type of field called a OnetoOne field. Have you looked into using a OnetoOne field? See: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield

Comment: When you say "it's still giving me an error" what is the actual error and have you removed the reference to the Business class from the ImageBank class?

Comment: The error is the same as before name 'Business' is not defined. Image bank was defined before business in the models.py changed the order

Comment: @ellieinphilly: Changing the order will do nothing because of the fact that you have a circular references to ForeignKeys between classes. The definitions of your classes will be read linearly, so either way, your app will throw an error about either Business being undefined, or ImageBank being undefined. Just for kicks, can you put your definition of ImageBank in your original post and specify which line is line 38?

Comment: @ellieinphilly: have you tried changing your use of ForeignKeys to something like `business = models.OneToOneField(Business, related_name='logo')` in the ImageBank class and removing the reference to logo from Business? Also, which line was line 38 in the edit?

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the models in the view? Something like:

```
from models import Business
```

at the beginning of the view file

Comment: I think the most simple solution (at least for development) is to use symbolic links

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import the model in the view, or you're referring to it incorrectly.

Comment: Why is your models.py not in a Django app?

Comment: there are multiple apps that refer to the same model hence we put it in a separate folder. common in itself is an app

Comment: So then import it from that, using the app name given in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: *Is* it listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0):

If that model is in an app you wrote:

Make sure that the app is listed in INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django....',
    ... more defaults ...,
    'myproject.appname',
)
```

and at the top of your views

```
#views.py
from appname.models import Business
#or import all models from that app
from appname.models import *
```

Comment: you could add your model folder to your Python path or create a symlink to the model in your django project folder, then you'd just call it as if it were there. If you think about it, many packages work like this, where they are located maybe in your site-/dist-packages and you call them from your django project through the python path.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things a lot more complicated on yourself by having your models.py in a strange unrelated location.

Models can only be imported from python modules so you'll need to make sure that your models.py is in a directory that is a python module and that it is on the python path.

You'll be a whole lot better of just putting your models into an app in your project rather than trying to do something like you are.

More or less you're working against the grain and python is a lot nicer if you work with the grain.